Math MCQs, arranging the given choices, the space between them, and some other (automatic) formatting
I am a new user of Latex, I only can write equations like in MSE, and never made a document in latex before.
I wanted to create MCQs, but MicrosoftWord is not better than Latex for this purpose, where I have tons (over 2000) of MCQs to write, with specific formatting.
I decided to watch some videos regading this, I found some good things. Also, I used AI to help me, it was ok, but not great. It did things that I could not understand, but some worked as I wanted.
My current Latex code is this:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{needspace}

\newcounter{problem}
\newcommand{\np}{%
  \par%
  \needspace{10\baselineskip}%
  \vspace{0.5\baselineskip}%
  \stepcounter{problem}%
  \textbf{Problem \theproblem:}\par
}
\newcommand{\ep}{\par\noindent\hrulefill}

\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}

\np 
If $f(x)=\sin(x)\cos(x)\sin(2x)\cos(2x)$, what is the value of $f'(0)$?
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item $0$
  \item $1$
  \item $\sqrt{2}$
  \item $2$
  \item $\pi$
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
Suppose that $f$ is a function on the interval $[1,3]$ such that $-1\le f(x)\le 1$ for all $x$ and $\int_{1}^{3}f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$. How large can $\int_{0}^{3}\frac{f(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ be?
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item $8$
  \item $\displaystyle\log\left(3+\frac{1}{3}\right)$
  \item $\displaystyle\log\left(2+\frac{1}{3}\right)$
  \item $\displaystyle\log\left(1+\frac{1}{3}\right)$
  \item $\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}\log(2)$
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
Let $A$, $B$, and $C$ be sets, and let $f:A\xrightarrow{}B$ and $g:B\xrightarrow{}C$ be functions. Which of the following is true?
\begin{enumerate}[label=\Roman*.,leftmargin=*]
    \item If $g\,\circ\,f$ is injective, then $f$ is injective.
    \item If $g\,\circ\,f$ is surjective, then $g$ is surjective.
    \item If $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective, then $g\,\circ\,f$ is bijective.
    \item If $g\,\circ\,f$ is bijective, then $f\,\circ\,g$ is identically zero.
    \item If $f\,\circ\,g=g\,\circ\,f$, then both $f$ and $g$ cannot be simultaneously bijective.
    \item If $f\,\circ\,g$ is injective, then $g\,\circ\,f$ can be either $0$ or $1$.
\end{enumerate}
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item I and II only
  \item I and III only
  \item II and III only
  \item III only
  \item III, IV, V and VI only
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
The region bounded by the $x$-axis and the function $f(x)=\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$ is rotated about the $x$-axis. What is the volume of the solid generated?
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
  \item $\dfrac{\pi}{3}$
  \item $\dfrac{\pi}{4}$
  \item $\pi$
  \item $2\pi$
  \item $\infty$
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
Let $f(x,y)=x^3-y^3+3x^2y-x$ for all real $x$ and $y$. Which of the following is true of $f$?
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item There is an absolute minimum at $\displaystyle\left(\dfrac{1}{3},\dfrac{1}{3}\right)$
   \item There is a relative maximum at $\displaystyle\left(-\dfrac{1}{3},-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)$
   \item There is a saddle point at $\displaystyle\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3},-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$
   \item There is an absolute maximum at $\displaystyle\left(-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3},\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{3}\right)$
   \item All critical values are on the line $y=x$
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
Find the general solution of
$$\displaystyle2\,\frac{\mathrm{d}^2y}{\mathrm{d}x^2}+9\,\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}x}-35y=0$$
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-7x}+C_2e^{\frac{5}{2}x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-\frac{5}{2}x}+C_2e^{7x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-7x}+C_2e^{5x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1e^{-5x}+C_2e^{7x}$
   \item $\displaystyle y=C_1\cos(5x)+C_2\cos(7x)$
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\np
Suppose today is Wednesday. What day of the week will it be $\displaystyle 10^{{10}^{10}}$ days from now?
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
   \item Sunday
   \item Monday
   \item Tuesday
   \item Wednesday
   \item Thursday
\end{enumerate}
\ep

\end{document}


Here are the things to be fixed: (I am not sure about the possibility of each one):

Whenever possible to write the choices in one line, do it automatically. For example, Problem 1 has short choices, and one line is sufficient. Something like this:




Some question have Roman numerals. The requirement is to let the leftmost character directly above the content of option A. Something like this:




After the last option of each question, a horizontal line must be drown, which I used \ep for it, I used that for End Problem. The line should be immediately after the last option, and if there is no enough space for that, move the question with its choices to the next page.

AI helped me to do the following only:
Any problem with its choices must not be partitioned into two pages, because in some cases, where the page is almost full of earlier question, a new question may not be enough to fit in the same page. AI did this correctly, but not for the horizontal line that should appear after the last option. For example:

The line above Problem 3, I used \ep after option E of Problem 2. However, When I used \ep after Problem 3, it appeared in a separate page. This does not meet the requirement (i.e. Problem & its choices $ horizontal line, all should appear together in one page).
Here is a good example of how it should look: (so this is correct):



The following may not be possible, I do not know, but I wish it is possible:

Whenever listing options in different lines (because one line is not enough), then I need (A),(B),(C),(D),(E) to be equally spaced. Some options contain large mathematical expressions which causes this space, this space is fine, but must be (EQUALLY SPACED)., It should look like this, (See option E, it has moved down (slightly)). D and E are closer in the crossed picture, whereas the picture on the right has A,B,C,D,E equally spaced.



I am annoyed with copying the command:
\begin{enumerate}[label=(\Alph*),leftmargin=*]
\item $0$
\item $1$
\item $\sqrt{2}$
\item $2$
\item $\pi$
\end{enumerate}
\ep


Cannot I define a new command, say \op for Options to speed up my typing, without copying that code each time?
Something (for example) like this:
What is 1+2+3?
\op 4
\op 5
\op 6
\op 7
\op 8
\ep

I wish to see some suggestions for my five points mentioned above. If you see my requirements are weird, excuse my as I am a new user, and I do not know what Latex can do and what cannot do. Also excuse me for my bad English (I am Arabic).
Your help would be appreciated. THANKS!

Welcome to TeX SE. Usually, we prefer if there is only one question per post. It'll be easier to answer. Also, have a look at the exam class. It'll solve some of your problem like the oneparchoices environment for your first part.

@AlainRemillard Thanks for sharing that. You are right, it will be easier when I post one question in the post. I will do so.

There are at least a couple of classes and/or packages for this, which will almost certainly be easier as @AlainRemillard mentioned. There are at least two exam classes ;). There are also solutions for typesetting sets of exercises and solutions. (I don't know if this is an exam or not.) In general, AI produces poor code, even when it appears to work. It also sometimes hallucinates packages which do not actually exist. Instead of starting there, try searching CTAN for solutions other people have contributed. Prefer recent but not super recent if you're not sure which to try.

@cfr thank you. I actually searched about some useful thing but never head about CTAN, as a am a new user. I will search CTAN, and also will see the exam provided by Alain Remillard. But the question now is: are the things I mentioned all possible? I am afraid one, or more, of them is impossible. Can you tell?

@Hussain-Alqatari I think they are all possible, but I am not 100% sure. I would also urge you not to go with 5. A custom syntax: fine. But keep some kind of \begin{mycustomenvironment}...\end{mycustomenvironment} (but mycustomenvironment can be much shorter!). This will make 1-4 easier. It will also make it much easier to debug your code in most editors. And it will make nasty surprises less likely. Set your editor up to produce the template text when you use a keyboard shortcut or press a button or whatever. There's no need to manually copy-paste. Are you working in English?

@cfr I use overleaf.com actually. But not sure if overleaf is limited to some features. And I do not know if there is any free software editors where my work can be done easily with its windows. Yes I am working in English.

@Hussain-Alqatari If you install TeX locally, you can use the editor of your choice. The vast majority of such editors and the two major distributions of TeX are free. 'Free' here means primarily free-as-in-freedom, but they are also free-as-in-beer. MikTeX was originally only available for Windows and is still primarily used on Windows. TeX Live is cross-platform and the distribution most commonly found packaged by Linux distros. There are any number of editors. TeX Live bundles an editor for Windows and Macs, but there are plenty of others. Non-free is the exception here.

@cfr I use Windows. And I will dig into CTAN and exam. Then if I face any problem, I will post them here separately, one for each post. THANKS cfr :-)
